# How to style multiple child elements based on parent element selector condition

Tags: html, css

Style multiple child elements

I have div in the DOM with id `#parentDiv`. This div has 2 elements a `<span>` and a `<div>`.

I want to style the inner span and inner div tag whenever I hover on the `#parentDiv`. How do I achieve this in traditional CSS way?

*Constraints* - This is do be done in the traditional css way.

Comment: What is 'traditional CSS way'?

Comment: Without less or sass architecture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML code it difficult to know exactly what will work, but this should:

```
#parentDiv:hover div {

}

#parentDiv:hover span {

}
```

With this, when the div is hovered over, the child span and div will have whatever styles you add within applied.

For example:

```css
#parentDiv:hover div {
color: blue;
}

#parentDiv:hover span {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv">
<div>Div Element</div>
<span> Span Element</span>
</div>
```

Comment: child selector isn't right here. one of them won't be direct descendant.

Comment: This is valid, check out [Mozilla's Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors). It's to select direct child elements.

Comment: Yeah, that should be noted, this wil only work on direct children of the parent element. For instance, if your HTML would look like this `<div id="parentDiv"><p>Text text <span>text</span> text</p></div>` than the span won't be affected (since it isn't a direct child). When using `#parentDiv:hover span` (without the `>`), than all span inside the parent element will be affected.

Comment: no one said it wasn't valid. am saying it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following syntax:

```
PARENT_SELECTOR:hover CHILD_SELECTOR {
    /* your css goes here */
}
```

For example,

```
#parent:hover #child {
    background: yellow;
}
```